# Windows internet connection only after deactivating and activating LAN adapter

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, lan, network-adapter

When I start my Window 7 PC I get no internet connection. LAN works, but internet does not. If I deactivate and then reactivate the LAN adapter, I get an internet connection.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I wonder if the process of restarting the adapter is starting a service?

Comment: I would suggest you to unplug and plug the network cable instead of disable/enable and check its works or not. Share the output of this step. So, we can move forward.

Comment: @DaveRook I had the "chance" to look if a service starts after reactivating the network adapter: but no service starts.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  Here are some suggestions to try.

Check your router dhcp settings.  If you assign static addresses, try deleting the static for your machine and then reboot the router & PC.

Or, if you define static on your PC NIC, remove it, and reboot getting an address from dhcp.  You can always define static addresses again.

If your router gives you options to clear the ARP table, do that too.

Comment: I have not changed the dhcp configuration between system starts with working and not working networking adapter. Everything looks as usual in the config.

Comment: @deamon, are you saying you are using dynamic or static IP on your machine?